# Accessing JSON Object property

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

These are my JSON objects.

```
({
"0":"http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F86040788&amp",
"1":"http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F87126537&amp",
"2":"http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F84915833&amp",
"3":"http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F87317484&amp",
"4":"http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F86548283&amp"
})
```

I fetched them with Ajax and this is how I get to them:

`data[0]` to `data[4]`.

Why is `data.1`, etc not working? I don't understand why I can access the objects like this `data[0]`, because they are not arrays.

Comment: Write your code and error messages.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the round parenthesis enclosing the curly brackets. See: http://json.org/example.html

Comment: the round parenthesis are for JSONP. And there is no error message, unless I try to acces my objects like this: data.0. My question is why I can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working with objects: Objects and properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or
>   anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty
>   string. **However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript
>   identifier (for example, a property name that has space or dash, or
>   starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket
>   notation.** This notation is also very useful when property names are to
>   be dynamically determined (when the property name is not determined
>   until runtime). Examples are as follows:

Answer (score 3):

> Why is data.1, etc is not working?

Thats because `data.1` is an invalid syntax according to the grammar of Javascript. Open your browsers console and try:

```
var obj = {};
obj[0] = "test";
obj.0; //SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

---

> I don't get why I can acess the objects like this data[0], because they are not arrays.

In javascript, arrays and map/dictionary/association array are the same thing. You can access by either `object[key]` syntax or `object.key` syntax. Only restriction is that it should be parseable by the parser (it should be an identifier), otherwise it would fail -- like the case you have. Another example:

```
var obj = {"test-data":1, "test": 2};
obj["test"]           // 2
obj.test              // 2
obj["test-data"];     // 1
obj.test-data         //ReferenceError: data is not defined
      //^ is a <MINUS> character, parsed as (obj.test - data)
```

Answer (score 0):

because json var name could not start from digit